# Python SQLITE not updating values

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to update a row. So I issued the command -

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("W:\\webtracker\\database\\webtracker.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT URL FROM WebsiteDetail where screenshot_processed = false")
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows: 
    cur.execute('''UPDATE WebsiteDetail SET screenshot_processed = true WHERE URL = ?''',(row[0],))
```

However, it doesnt update the value. What is the problem?

There is not error being thrown

row[0] is a string

Comment: Why not simply: `UPDATE WebsiteDetail SET screenshot_processed = true WHERE screenshot_processed = false`?

Comment: You do not `COMMIT`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit these changes. Your for loop should look like this:

```py
for row in rows: 
    cur.execute('''UPDATE WebsiteDetail SET screenshot_processed = true WHERE URL = ?''',(row[0],))
    conn.commit()
```